# Docker-compose makes system freeze with chrome open [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, docker

My system specs:

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. docker 1.12.1 (client & server)
3. docker-compose (1.8.0)
4. google-chrome (53.0.2785.116)

I have tried using several window managers (unity, awesome, gnome 3) and it happens for all of them. When following this steps:

- Open chrome
- docker-compose up
  UI freezes and system starts to hang and lag constantly, making impossible to work until reboot. However, if I use docker-compose up without chrome open and then opening it aftetwards it works as expected.

If I need to rerun docker-compose and I close chrome before doing it and opening it up afterwards it also works.

Comment: Bizarre. Is it for any `docker-compose.yml` file, or just one specific one?

Comment: For any docker-compose.yml. I just found out that this happens randomly and does not matter whether or not I have chrome open. It simply breaks randomly.

Comment: Ridiculous! I and two my colleagues are facing the same issue :) We are using docker-compose 1.7.1, chrome version is 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit). What is interesting another colleague is using the same stack except that he uses chrome 52.bla-bla version. Will try to check if that is an issue's source.